# Upload folder with cURL and FTP using Batch file on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, ftp, batch-file, curl

I am trying to upload a whole folder, including it's sub-folders and files to a folder on my server from a Windows batch (.bat) file.

Below is the command I have for the Upload part...

```
curl -T E:\Server\bootstrap3\_gh_pages\ -u USER:PASSWORD ftp://domain.com/bootstrap/
```

This is the error I get

```
curl: Can't open 'E:\Server\bootstrap3\_gh_pages\'!
curl: try 'curl --help' for more information
```

If I try to do just 1 file, it works fine, I need to somehow loop through and do all folders and files, any help please?

I have Googled and tried a couple not very good examples with no luck on this exact question yet

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that curl doesn't cycle through the directory, there is no option for uploading the whole directory and it doesn't support *-expansion. So the solution I ended up with is to write a .bat script. With the help of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9429985

```
@echo off 
set localdir=C:\something
set ftphost=your.ftp.host.com
set ftpuser=yourftpuser
set ftppass=yourftppassword
set ftpdir=target/directory/on/server

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /F %%x in ('dir /B/D %localdir%') do (
  set FILENAME=%localdir%\%%x
  curl -T !FILENAME! ftp://%ftphost%/%ftpdir%/ --user %ftpuser%:%ftppass%
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Not useful for Windows, but on Linux you can combine curl and find:

```
find /server/ -exec curl -T {} ftp://some-ftp-site/folder/ --user user:pass \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since curl was written for *nix (unix), there can be problems specifying working commands from the Windows Command Prompt. This is mostly related to the processing of **`"`** (double-quote) marks, and **`\`** (backslashes).

A simple thing you can try is:

1. Enclose filenames in double-quotes.
2. Escape the backslashes by adding another backslash before each desired backslash.

So, like this:

```
curl -T "E:\\Server\\bootstrap3\\_gh_pages\\" -u USER:PASSWORD ftp://domain.com/bootstrap/
```

You could also try using forward-slashes like this, which ***might*** work:

```
curl -T "E:/Server/bootstrap3/_gh_pages/" -u USER:PASSWORD ftp://domain.com/bootstrap/
```

Another thing you could try is to use the **`-K`** (or **`--config=`**) command line option switch for curl (some helpful information can be found [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)).

Basically, you place all the command line arguments in a file and use **`-K file`** (or **`--config=file`**) to tell curl where to find the arguments.

So, you create a file (example: test.txt) that has each command line option on a separate line like this:

```
-T "E:\\Server\\bootstrap3\\_gh_pages\\"
-u USER:PASSWORD
--url=ftp://domain.com/bootstrap/
```

Then run curl like this:

```
curl -K test.txt
  or
curl --config=test.txt
```

---

If none of this works, you may need to run the curl command from a Cygwin terminal window on Windows. See [this webpage](http://hariniachala.blogspot.com/2012/08/running-curl-commands-in-command-prompt.html) for info on using curl with Cygwin on Windows.

Comment: Am just curious, any particular reason why you didn't undelete your original answer, and edit it if required?

Answer (score 1):

Like the Linux solution posted earlier, in Windows you would do:

forfiles /p C:\uploads /c "curl.exe -C -# -T @path ftp://some-ftp-site/folder/@file --user user:pass"